# To use React FC on functions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, react-props

I want to learn how to use `React.FC<>` in normal functions on react.js.

I know there are two type of functions; the first is (the one that I prefer):

```
  function Welcome(props) {
      return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
    }
```

The other one is  something like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      "& > * + *": {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
      },
    },
  })
);
```

I have been told that if I want to use `React.FC<>`   on functions I should do it like this :

```
const QuestionCard: React.FC<Props>  = () => (
     <div>Question Card</div>
);

export default QuestionCard;
```

But I don't want to do it with `const functions` (if that is how it's called). I want to do it with the normal function. I have tried it like this:

```
export default function QuestionCard : React.FC<Props>() {

  //duda
  return <div>Question Card</div>;
}
```

But the code editor shows me an error like this:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlnEx.png)

Comment: Don't use `React.FC`. [It is unnecessary and it provides next to no benefits and has a few downsides](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In typescript you can't apply a type alias to a function *statement*. You are limited to typing the arguments and return type separately.

```
function foo(arg1: Arg1Type, arg2: Arg2Type): MyReturnType {
  //...
}
```

But if you have a function type alias, you must use this form instead:

```
type MyFn = (arg1: Arg1Type, arg2: Arg2Type) => MyReturnType
const foo: MyFn = (arg1, arg2) => {
  //...
}
```

That's just the way to the syntax works. What all that means is that if you want to use the `React.FC<Props>` type alias for your functional component, then you must use the `const MyComponent: React.FC<Props>`

---

However, (Warning: this drifts into opinion from here on) I want to add that you don't really need the `React.FC` at all. All it *really* gives you an extra `children?: React.ReactNode` prop, which don't want on every component anyway. In fact, if a component does not allow children, and you pass some to it anyway, then I would expect a type error. `React.FC` doesn't make it easy to be explicit about that.

For example:

```
interface Props {
  foo: string
}

// A React.FC declared component that should not take children.
const MyComponentC: React.FC<Props> = ({ foo }) => {
  return <>{ foo }</>
}
const c = <MyComponentC foo='bar' /> // expected usage
const cWithChildren = <MyComponentC foo='bar'>some children</MyComponentC> // no type error
```

That component is not explicitly typed to accept children, and yet it does. It would be nice if there was a type error.

Instead, lets look at two examples that don't use `React.FC` and instead declare `children` explicity.

```
// A function statement declared component that takes no children.
function MyComponentA({ foo }: Props) {
  return <>Foo: {foo}</>
}
const a = <MyComponentA foo='bar' />
const aWithChildren = <MyComponentA foo='bar'>some children</MyComponentA> // type error


// A function statement declared component that DOES take children.
function MyComponentB({ foo, children }: PropsWithChildren) {
  return <>
    <p>Foo: {foo}</p>
    <p>{children}</p>
  </>
}
const b = <MyComponentB foo='bar' /> // type error
const bWithChildren = <MyComponentB foo='bar'>some children</MyComponentB>
```

Now the presence of children is enforced by the type system, and the syntax for declaring the component is clean and simple in all cases.

For these reasons, I wouldn't really recommend using `React.FC` these days.

[Typescript playground with above example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-beta&ssl=28&ssc=75&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoC4AOxiSk3STgAUcwBnOAbwrjkwQIALjgcYUGgHMKAXwpVa9RmmZsInAOrAYACwDCu4ABsAJkWo8+AoaPGTqM8vzRGzF0cnQwAdF4wAchCmSHIK5AD0EXAAggIArtQYwBCW4ih0IEi0cCFoxihEpnBouJDU2fB6GXAwKADWSFzUECVu5tk+FJiJyalwALIAnvplqZUxABTcNq2youqcAJRWznBEMPFQlgA8AHwAYrY8ghCyOxF7YeSl1OJwKHAAvHA7w6Pg47Rxp0-4AEaFfBwS4UW73FDaPSGEwdSwvN4jMYVb6zP6AqD4PYcXDMVywiwXd7IiZ7EHRGBDMDMeg4KDhChRWIJJIwFJpOqZSq5JD5QpIYqlT4oqq6GoAEQA8gBRADKtQaePaFi65B6rPZgyRwsqACFprMADRtAnZODzVjsDhQgzK7IrXhrDZbXZXNb8HZgQ7Hbinc4RL3WD1e7j49zZf2BtYXN3yG6pe7-Z6vYk62i6tEAoEgslMynUuC06BghPwf42mHh+Ep7XlPWZjFYnFZE1Vom1r4wXVu8JMuL+XwHfQ8vlFEoknLVeAcXQQeJmOAtKqK1tw1Xg+Cpuu0fSeYiD-Q7RYcMkvA2nc0rJ5kx38Z3bV57GYX-2xkt3eBoZOIj7bmDD34s0xHNyUXVp8xpKA6Xfe40ArO1qx-Cd-wbIFsVxVdCQiLdO30XNohaWoqUg6DyCAA)